# IE won't center <main> and it's content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, centering

This CSS works on firefox and chrome, but for some weird reason it wont work on `IE` =(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>I hate u, ie :p</title>

    <style>
    header>nav, main, footer>nav {
        max-width: 500px;
        padding: 0em;
        margin: 0em auto;
        }
    header, footer { min-width: 100%; background-color: #c0c0c0;}

    main { background-color: yellow; }
    main>section, main>aside { display: inline-block; }
    main>section    { background-color: aqua; }
    main>aside      { background-color: pink; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<header>
    <nav>
    <ul><li>Header is centered =)</li></ul>
    </nav>

    <nav>
    <ul><li>Header (nemu 2) is centered =)</li></ul>
    </nav>
</header>


<main>
    <section>
    <h1>Why IE won't center me?</h1>
    </section>

    <aside>
    <p>Stackoverflow: please help me</p>
    </aside>
</main>


<footer>
    <nav>
    <ul><li>Footer is centered =)</li></ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate it if you help me fix this, preferably without adding/removing elements. I'd like to keep the current semantic if possible. If not, o well...

It is worth to mention that if I do something like `<main><div>...</div></main>` and add `main>div { margin: 0em auto;}` IE (and all other browsers, as expected) center `main`'s content. But like I mentioned, I'd like to not break the semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE does not support the main element. To get it to work, however, you can just set `main { display:block; }` and it will work. This is a similar fix to the other new HTML5 elements, such as section and nav, which weren't supported but could be added by just adding that CSS.

Comment: That was clever. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough reputation, I post my idea as an answer:

My guess is, that you have to add `position: relative;` for your `.main`.

Browsers have a `default.css` with default values for keys you didn't set. I think (but didn't check) the IE has different std-values than other browsers. That could cause problems.

Comment: Just because you don't have enough reputation to post a comment doesn't mean you should circumvent that restriction by posting comments as answers.

Comment: Okay, next time I don't. I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

The main element is not supported in IE:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)
- [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=main)

Which I believe means there is no default styling for the `main` element, so you will have to add it. Most reset stylesheets will do this for you for the newer, more semantic elements.

Add `display: block` to your CSS selector for `main` and it should work.

```css
main {
    display: block;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @mr-lister That is a really good observation =)   Me too, i'd like to know

Comment: _Not Supported_ means, I believe, that there are no default styles for the element. If you supply them, then they should get used.

Comment: @MrLister - For `<main>`, the most important thing that a browser must do to support it, is to expose it to the platform accessibility API as the place of a WAI-ARIA main landmark role. More generally, elements whose type is HTMLUnknownElement could reasonably be considered unsupported.